# Twig filter not working in 'web' folder of Symfony2 project

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a custom Twig filter called 'markdown' installed and working in a twig file located here:

```
/src/Imagine/NewsletterBundle/Resources/views/Section/build_intro.html.twig
```

Here is the markup:

```
{{ article.excerpt | markdown }}
```

I also want to use this filter within a twig template located here:

```
/web/templates/WebDesigner/intro.html.twig
```

But I try to use it I get the following error message:

```
The filter "markdown" does not exist in intro.html.twig at line 12
```

Is this because the web folder is outside the scope of the bundle I am using? How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score -1):

Have you added your filter to twig enviroment? If so, you should look to create twig extensions
[Create twig extensions](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension)